# Binding a conditional variable from an array

Tags: arrays, data-binding, pdo, conditional-statements

I'm trying to convert my old MySQLI query into a PDO, while also binding all variables to protect against injection. This particular query gets its "WHERE" conditions from an array.

```
$w=array();
if ($pos!='') $w[]="PositionId=':pos'";
if ($country!='') $w[]="CountryId=':country'";
if ($current!='') $w[]="IsCurrent=':current'";
if ($c1stat!='') $w[]=":c1stat :c1comp ':c1val'";
if ($c2stat!='') $w[]=":c2stat :c2comp ':c2val'";
if ($c3stat!='') $w[]=":c3stat :c3comp ':c3val'";
if ($c4stat!='') $w[]=":c4stat :c4comp ':c4val'";
if (count($w)) $where="WHERE ".implode(' AND ',$w); else $where='';

$query="SELECT * FROM table $where";
$result = $pdo->prepare($query);
$result->bindParam(':pos', $pos);
$result->bindParam(':country', $country);
$result->bindParam(':iscurrent', $current);
$result->bindParam(':c1stat', $c1stat); $result->bindParam(':c1comp', $c1comp); $result->bindParam(':c1val', $c1val);
$result->bindParam(':c2stat', $c2stat); $result->bindParam(':c2comp', $c2comp); $result->bindParam(':c2val', $c2val);
$result->bindParam(':c3stat', $c3stat); $result->bindParam(':c3comp', $c3comp); $result->bindParam(':c3val', $c3val);
$result->bindParam(':c4stat', $c4stat); $result->bindParam(':c4comp', $c4comp); $result->bindParam(':c4val', $c4val);
$result->execute();
```

I am still trying to understand PDO and binding variables, so I'm struggling to get going on this one.

The $query is being built correctly, for example, a WHERE statement with a $country condition produced:

```
SELECT * FROM skaterRScareer WHERE PositionId>='2' AND CountryId=':country'
```

So why is the variable not bound?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind anything but **data literals**:

- string literals - okay
- number literals - okay
- part of string literal - fail
- identifiers - fail
- operators - fail
- functions - fail
- syntax keywords - fail
- arbitrary query part - fail

So - alas! - there is no placeholder for the operators or identifiers.
You have to whitelist them instead.

There is another problem with your code. 
You have to bind variables for only placeholders that actually made it into query

Look, if `$c3stat` is empty, there will be no `:c3stat :c3comp :c3val` placeholders in the query - so, you should not bind corresponding variables as well

Make it

```
if ($c3val) {
    $w[] = "some field > :c3val";
    $values[":c3val"] = $c3val;
}
```

Also there is no need to add quotes around placeholders.

Here is an example on whitelisting

```
$fields     = array("name","price","qty");
$operators  = array(">","<","=");
$fkey       = array_search($_GET['sort'],$orders));
$okey       = array_search($_GET['sort'],$orders));
if ($fkey !== FALSE && $okey !== FALSE) { 
    $field  = $fields[$fkey]; 
    $op     = $operators[$okey]; 
    $query .= "$field $op :placeholder";
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how to whitelist an identifier?

Comment: I've updated my answer. By the way, it seems you're using my old code to handle conditional queries :) Glad it worked for you before and glad to help again. If I get time, I'll rewerite that old code to PDO.

Comment: thanks for the example! you have a couple typos (extra parenthesis on $fkey and $okey / also not sure what $orders references) But I got it working with your help!